# VerneMQ enable mqtts protocol on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, mqtt-vernemq

I'm using helm chart to deploy VerneMQ on Kubernetes cluster using the [instructed steps](https://github.com/vernemq/docker-vernemq/tree/master/helm/vernemq#enable-mqtts) to enable mqtts.

values.yaml

```yaml
service:
  mqtts:
    enabled: true
secretMounts:
  - name: vernemq-certificates
    secretName: vernemq-cert
    path: /etc/ssl/vernemq
additionalEnv:
  - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_ACCEPT_EULA
    value: "yes"
  - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_LISTENER__SSL__CAFILE
    value: "/etc/ssl/vernemq/tls.crt"
  - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_LISTENER__SSL__CERTFILE
    value: "/etc/ssl/vernemq/tls.crt"
  - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_LISTENER__SSL__KEYFILE
    value: "/etc/ssl/vernemq/tls.key"
  - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_LISTENER__SSL__DEFAULT
    value: "127.0.0.1:8883"
  - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_LISTENER__TCP__DEFAULT
    value: "127.0.0.1:8883"
```

The verne-cluster is successfuly deployed but it's not listening on port 8883. The client is disconnected with error `Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established`.

I tested the connection using a tcp nginx ingress, `port-frowarding` and using `nc` tool from a debug pod on the same namespace to test the port, all indicating the port 8883 was not listening. However the service is enabled for it and inside the container, the service indicates is open.

```bash
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9100            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      126/beam.smp
tcp        0      0 10.255.21.22:8080       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      126/beam.smp
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4369            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      186/epmd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8883          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      126/beam.smp
tcp        0      0 10.255.21.22:44053      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      126/beam.smp
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8888          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      126/beam.smp
tcp        0      0 10.255.21.22:8888       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      126/beam.smp
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1883          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      126/beam.smp
tcp        0      0 :::4369                 :::*                    LISTEN      186/epmd
```

The only lead I have is the in the `error.log`, but I've try a fiew configuration variables and none have worked out

`[error] <0.434.0>@vmq_ranch_config:reconfigure_listeners_for_type:{269,13} can't reconfigure mqtts listener({127,0,0,1}, 8883) with Options [{max_connections,10000},{nr_of_acceptors,10},{mountpoint,[]},{cafile,"/etc/ssl/vernemq/tls.crt"},{depth,1},{certfile,"/etc/ssl/vernemq/tls.crt"},{eccs,[secp521r1,brainpoolP512r1,brainpoolP384r1,secp384r1,brainpoolP256r1,secp256k1,secp256r1,secp224k1,secp224r1,secp192k1,secp192r1,secp160k1,secp160r1,secp160r2]},{keyfile,"/etc/ssl/vernemq/tls.key"},{require_certificate,false},{tls_version,'tlsv1.2'},{use_identity_as_username,false},{allowed_protocol_versions,[3,4,131]},{allow_anonymous_override,false}] due to {already_started,<0.458.0>}`

Comment: Were you able to get this to work because I'm stuck in the same exact spot.

Comment: No, I ended up using plain TCP and let my HA Proxy IngressClass handle the TLS offloading

Comment: I ended up taking the same approach only I used traefik and cert-manager to get the job done. It was a pretty confusing problem to work through but now that it's working it seems to work really well.